# MarkupBuilder - how to add table td attribute "title"

Tags: grails

I am looking to add table td "title" attribute along with td content. is there any way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used groovy markup builder in the context of grails tags libs, I share a small custom tag with the requirement that you mention. See how the title attribute is added to the td tag

```
import groovy.xml.*

def table = {
    MarkupBuilder mb = new MarkupBuilder(out)

    mb.table {
        thead {
            tr {
                th 'Col1'
                th 'Col2'
                th 'Col3'
            }
        }

        tbody {
            tr {
                td(title: 'lorem ipsum') {
                    mb.yield 'Text1'
                }

                td 'Text1'

                td 'Text1'
            }

            tr {
                td(title: 'lorem ipsum') {
                    mb.yield 'Text2'
                }

                td 'Text2'

                td 'Text2'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the view you can invoke the new tag in this way, assuming you use the namespace location

```
<location:table/>
```

This will draw the following table in the browser

[image]

It's certainly not pretty but it's made with markup builder and it has some td with the title attribute.

This [link](https://objectcomputing.com/resources/publications/sett/december-2015-custom-gsp-tags-grails-best-kept-secret/) is an excellent resource to understand tags libs in grails and contains examples using markup builder

For how to use markup builder in a context other than grails tag libs, visit this [post](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/10/groovy-goodness-creating-xml-with.html) of who else if not Mr Haki

I hope it is useful for you

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Javascript/Jquery. Try below code:

```
$('td').on('mouseover', function(){
  var td = $(this);
  td.attr('title', td.html())
})
```

Comment: I think the question is about how to get the MarkupBuilder to generate the `title` attribute.

Comment: Got it. I missed the questions main part. Thanks.